# How do I recover production data in App Engine that I accidentally deleted?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, versioning, database-backups, backup-strategies

I deleted some data from my production App Engine app. Unfortunately I had the wrong table name in mind when I did so because I have two tables that have very similar names. I know the deployed code is versioned so you can roll back to a previous version of your code. What about for your data? And, going forward, what's the best data backup strategy to use for production data?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry Keith your data is lost. Backups are the responsibility of the user.

There is a feature request [Datastore archive](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=776&q=snapshot&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) which you should star if you think something like this should be part of the service and an improved Import/Export is on the [roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html).

For now your best options are:

- Use the [Bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data) to fetch all your entities
- Write a custom offsite backup script that fetches important parts of your data via remote_api
- Periodically copy all your entities into a different namespace in the datastore (this can be trickier that it sounds)